# Is it possible to print the UI Content Presented on Screen | Swift

Tags: swift, printing

Essentially I have UI View that presents on screen and takes up the entire phones screen, I would  like to be able to select a button and print what is currently presented on the screen over AirPrint. Is something like this possible? Are there libraries or other ways of achieving this?

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Do you want to capture the whole screen view and print?

Comment: Yes exactly, everything currently presented on the screen I would like to send to be printed - if possible the same size as the device. Small Phone, small picture printed.

Comment: @NahidRaihan Is this possible?

Comment: yes ... giving u a solution.. give me some time

Comment: Ah apologies, thank you

Comment: Given a solution , if it's work , then vote please .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1:** First for converting your UIView into image , add this extension:

```
extension UIView {
 func toImage() -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, false, UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)

    drawViewHierarchyInRect(self.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)

    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image
 }
}
```

**Step 2:** Add this into your button action for print:

```
@IBAction func printButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    let printInfo = UIPrintInfo(dictionary:nil)
    printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputType.General
    printInfo.jobName = "My UIView"

    let printController = UIPrintInteractionController.sharedPrintController()
    printController.printInfo = printInfo

   
    printController.printingItem = self.view.toImage()

    // If you want to specify a printer
    guard let printerURL = URL(string: "Your printer URL here, e.g. ipps://HPDC4A3E0DE24A.local.:443/ipp/print") else { return }
    guard let currentPrinter = UIPrinter(url: printerURL) else { return }                     

    printController.print(to: currentPrinter, completionHandler: nil)

    printController.presentFromRect(self.view.frame, inView: self.view, animated: true, completionHandler: nil)
}
```